# Pass map data portfolio to my component cards

Tags: reactjs

I have a component card and I want it to be more generic so that it displays the information according to the parent component and the database to use, but I can't.

For now, I have TypeError feedback: Cannot read property 'map' of undefined

it works if I put the map in the card but therefore if I want to use the component cards in another container which has another address API I have to make it more generic.

Component Cards child

```
 const Card = ({ techno, webLink }, props) => {
  const { dataCards, imageBaseURL } = props;
  
  // Directory Images
  // const imageBaseURL = 'https://irimaxserver.irimax-dev.fr/uploads/';

  // const [dataCards, setDataCard] = useState([]);
  // const [isLoading, setIsLoading] = useState(false);

  useEffect((err) => {
    // setIsLoading(true);
    // axios
    //   .get('https://irimaxserver.irimax-dev.fr/api/v1/cards')

    //   .then((res) => {
    //     console.log(res);
    //     setIsLoading(false);
    //     setDataCard(res.data.data);
    //   })
    //   .catch(err);
    Aos.init({ once: true });
  }, []);

  return (
    <div className='container-card'>
      {dataCards.map((dataCard) => (
        <div
          key={dataCard._id}
          className='wrapper'
          data-aos='zoom-in-up'
          data-aos-easing='ease-out-cubic'
          data-aos-duration='3000'
        >
          <div className='card'>
            <div>
              <img
                className='card_image'
                src={`${imageBaseURL}${dataCard.image}`}
                alt='zen'
              />
            </div>
            <div className='card_name'>{dataCard.titleProject}</div>
            <div className='card_type'>
              {dataCard.inProgress === true ? 'En cours de réalisation' : ''}
            </div>
```

Container portfolio parent

```
    const Portfolio = () => {
  
 
    // Directory Images
    const imageBaseURL = 'http://localhost:5000/uploads/';

    const [dataCards, setDataCard] = useState([]);
    const [isLoading, setIsLoading] = useState(false);
  
    useEffect((err) => {
      setIsLoading(true);
      axios
        .get('http://localhost:5000/api/v1/cards')
  
        .then((res) => {
          console.log(res);
          setIsLoading(false);
          setDataCard(res.data.data);
        })
        .catch(err);
      
    }, []);
    if (isLoading) {
      return <Spinner />;
    } else {
  return (
    
    <div>
      <h1 className='title_portfolio'>Ils nous ont fait confiance !</h1>
      
      <Card dataCards={dataCards} imageBaseURL={imageBaseURL} />
      
    </div>
  );
}};
```

Answer (score 0):

In portfolio component, particularly in then block `setDataCard(res.data.data || [])` this will set the value of setDataCard to an empty array even if api responds with null or undefined or anything falsy. also `setIsLoading(false);` in finally block

```
axios.get('http://localhost:5000/api/v1/cards').then((res) => {
      console.log(res);
      setIsLoading(false);
      setDataCard(res.data.data || []);
    })
    .catch(err)
    .finally(()=>setIsLoading(false));
```

Comment: thank you but my concern is to pass the values retrieved in porfolio to the cards component

Comment: thanks for your help i found i was having a hard time passing my props

Answer (score 0):

one common approach to avoid errors from mapping undefined variables is to use `&&` operator which will only execute the second part if the first is truthy. so you would write like:

```
{dataCards && dataCards.map( ...code here) }
```

fwiw, I would consider to rename your `Card` component to `CardList` or `Cards`, to reflect with more precision what the component really is, a colletion of cards.

Comment: Thanks for tip dataCards && dataCards.map
therefore it displays the page but it does not retrieve the information retrieved from porfolio to pass them to cards and the name actually I changed it is always difficult to find a correct name

Comment: thanks for your help i found i was having a hard time passing my props

Comment: like you have a tree Portfolio > Containter > SmallContainer > Cards and wanna pass props from Portfolio to Cards directly?